# Where to deploy devops self hosted agents in a hub and spoke architecture

Tags: azure, azure-devops, architecture, agent

Is the hub the best place to deploy self hosted agents in its own subnet or it is better to use ephemeral pipeline with agents in the subnet of the ressources it needs to run its job in?
I have tried to find all different possibilities but couldnt find a reference architecture from Microsoft. I also saw some post talking about having the self hosted agents in its own spoke??

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you can include specific examples and explain things that you have tried so far. As is, this is very open-ended and any answer is probably going to require a lot of assumptions that may or may not be valid in your situation.